# como faço para executar um arquivo.php?

Tags: php

Tenho um a pagina em `php` e gostaria de executar outro código em `php` mais não estou conseguindo alguém pode me dizer o que estou fazendo de errado:

```
if ($_GET["URL"] === 'WEEK' || $_GET["URL"] === 'week'){
    $obj = new COM("WScript.Shell");

    if (is_object($obj)){
        $obj->Run ("week.php");
    }else{
        echo "Não foi possível criar o objeto!";
    }

}
```

Answer (score 1):

Você pode executar um comando para o [sistema operacional utilizando crases junto](http://php.net/manual/pt_BR/language.operators.execution.php) com o comando de console:

```
$retorno = `php -f week.php`;
```

Veja um exemplo no [Ideone](https://ideone.com/iPznB3).

É importante observar se a [configuração `safe_mode`](http://php.net/manual/pt_BR/ini.sect.safe-mode.php#ini.safe-mode) está **desabilitada**.

**Porém essa abordagem que você está tomando é insegura!!**

Como você vai garantir que o código que será executado não foi modificado, não é malicioso? Existem outras formas de resolver o problema. Se chamar um arquivo PHP a partir do console dentro do PHP, existe algo de errado.

Comment: não funcionou essa sujestão sua

Comment: @chapolin funciona sim https://ideone.com/iPznB3 Verifique a configuração do seu PHP, em específico o safe_mode http://php.net/manual/pt_BR/language.operators.execution.php